# How to compare MPEG-7 Video Signature signatures

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg

I want to get a measure of similarity of two videos by using their precomputed [MPEG-7 video signatures](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#signature-1). While ffmpeg supports comparing two videos for a match by inputting the videos directly I can't find a way to compare the signature files (bin or xml) later without the original video files.

After digging through some ffmpeg code I found these lines [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a0ac49e38ee1d1011c394d7be67d0f08b2281526/libavfilter/vf_signature.c#L627) and [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a0ac49e38ee1d1011c394d7be67d0f08b2281526/libavfilter/signature_lookup.c#L533), but I am stuck.

Is there a simple way to compute a similarity score with those MPEG-7 video signature files?

Answer (score 2):

I found your question while looking for an answer to this myself. Having solved my more limited problem (I am a dabbler - I only need to detect matches, only use the coarse signatures, and don't care about localising the match), I can offer the following comments.

- The ffmpeg source links to a paper, *The MPEG-7 Video Signature Tools for Content Identification*, that provides an example three-stage scheme for pair-wise matching (see part VII), which ffmpeg seems to have adopted. I am not sure that a comparison of signatures in this way can actually give you a continuous measure of similarity - like the ffmpeg output, it seems that it will just tell you whether you have a match, and among those matches which is the best/longest.
- Coarse matching is determined by calculating the Jaccard distances between combinations of "segments" from both signatures and comparing the distances with various thresholds. You may be able to use these distances as the foundation of a similarity score, but it seems there would be a lot of choices to be made in doing so. For example, is a five second excerpt from a ten second clip fully similar (as every frame in the first clip is drawn from the second) or only fifty percent similar (as only half the frames of the second clip are present in the first?) Alternative approaches might base the similarity score on the threshold at which two clips stop registering as matches.
- The reference software accompanying the standard (part 6) is described as including software 'to compute distances between descriptions for the purpose of indexing' (see [here](https://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-7/reference-software)). Unfortunately the standard is very expensive, so I haven't seen this implementation.